# How to send message to only caller client in SignalR?

Tags: signalr

Below is my SignalR Hub class code.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }


    public async void webAPIRequest()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        //Clients.All.addWebAPIResponseToPage(response);
        Clients.Caller.addWebAPIResponseToPage(response);

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");

        Clients.Caller.addWebAPIResponseToPage(response);
        //Clients.All.addWebAPIResponseToPage(response);

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        response = await client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1");
        //Clients.All.addWebAPIResponseToPage(response);
        Clients.Caller.addWebAPIResponseToPage(response);

    }

}
```

As per my understanding ,

```
Clients.Caller.addWebAPIResponseToPage(response);
```

sends message only to caller client , whereas

Clients.All.addWebAPIResponseToPage(response);

sends the message to all the clients.

1. Is my understanding correct ?
2. If No , then what method needs to be called to send message only to caller client.

Answer (score 6):

Yes your understanding is correct. Read it here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients

You can use caller, you can provide current user connection id and send message to that or I have seen a group called self in some places which keeps user logged in from various devices and send message to that.

For example if you are logged in on a desktop and on mobile as well then you will have two connection IDs but you are same user. You can add this user to a self_username_unique_group_name kind of group and then send a message to that group which will be sent to all devices where user is connected.

You can also manage connection IDs for a single user in a separate table and send message to all of those connection IDs if you want.

Too much flexibility and magic
Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work quite well where ConnectionMapping is described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<SomeService>();
        services.AddScoped<SessionService>();
        services.AddScoped<ProgressHub>();
    }
}

public class SomeService 
{
    ProgressHub _hub;

    public SomeService(ProgressHub hub)
    {
        _hub = hub;
    }

    private async Task UpdateProgressT(T value)
    {
        _hub.Send(value);
    }
}



public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = new ConnectionMapping<string>();
    private readonly IHubContext<ProgressHub> _context;
    private readonly SessionService _session;

    public ProgressHub(IHubContext<ProgressHub> context, SessionService session)
    {
        _context = context;
        _session = session;
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {            
        _connections.Add(_session.SiteId, Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {            
        _connections.Remove(_session.SiteId, Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }        
        
    public async Task Send(object data)
    {            
        foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(_session.SiteId))
        {
            await _context.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("Message", data);
        }
    }
}


public class SessionService
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public SessionService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _session = accessor.HttpContext.Session;

        if (_session == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("session");
    }   

    public string SiteId
    {
        get => _session.GetString("SiteId");
        set => _session.SetString("SiteId", value);
    }
}
```